# Clearing socket.io event handler inside an iterator

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have an iterator or some kind of a job that runs every 2 seconds. Inside this job I have a socket io event handler. Everytime this event handler it being executed, the value it passes to the server becomes multiplied.

Here is my code:

```
function job() {

  // SENDS DATA TO THE SERVER
  app.io.emit('data', {name: 'test'});

  let delay = setTimeout(()=>{
     job();
  }, 2000);
}
```

The second time the job executes, it throws the data `{name: 'test'}` twice to the server and so on. . . Is there a way to prevent this like clear the event handler before it executes again? From what I have understood, it creates a new event handler eveyrtime the `app.io.emit()` is executed. Thanks